# Audio KJV Bible in British accent

Tags: support

I am not sure this is where I can ask this question, it didn't seem right on the actual BHSE. I would like to ask if anyone has any idea whether an audio KJV Bible exists read with British accent. If there is a free version, that would be great, but I do not mind purchasing one.
It seems awfully difficult to find one, as if only the Americans read the KJV, which can't be true :)...

If this is not the right site please tell me where I can navigate. Would be grateful.

Comment: YouVersion sounds like it has a British reader? https://www2.bible.com/bible/1/GEN.20.KJV Also available in the Bible App for Android/iPhone.

Comment: @curiousdannii That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: The Dwell app (paid but has a free trial to see if you like it) also has lots of accented English readers from America, Britain, Africa, and I think Asia somewhere... I just glanced over and noticed they're all different versions so I'm not sure if any of the KJV ones are British.